# Solving matrix PDE with a range of free parameters

Tags: differential-equations

I've a matrix PDE which looks like,
$$
\partial_r M(r,k) = M(r,k) \, A(k) \, M(r,k) \, + B(k) \quad, \quad \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \, M(r,k) = C(k)
$$ 
Here $M,A,B,C$ are all $4\times4$ matrices and functions of $r$ and/or $k$. One more thing is this equation has to be solved for a range of $k$ and in the end I want a plot of $\text{Tr} \,(\text{Im}\, M)$ vs $k$. I'm not sure how to solve a matrix equation and that to with a range of parameters.

Let me put this simple $2 \times 2$ example as reference (say for $k \in [-2,2]$ ): 
$$
A(k) = \begin{pmatrix} k & -1 \\ -1 & -k \end{pmatrix} \, , \,
B(k) = \begin{pmatrix} k & 1 \\ 1 & -k \end{pmatrix} \, , \, 
C(k) = \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{k} & 0 \\ 0 & -\sqrt{k} \end{pmatrix} \, .
$$
(Please feel free to change the $A$, $B$, and $C$ matrices if needed, as I'm not sure of the existence of the solution for these choices.)

Thanks!

Comment: Use `ParametricNDSolve` and treat `k` as the parameter.

Comment: please post Mathematica code, not just TeX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NB. I am not an expert in PDE's, but I would like to put an answer here in hopes that it would lead to better answers.

Since $k$ is a parameter, I have removed it from the arguments to $M$. Then, I specified the matrices directly in the differential equation and the inital value.

```
soln = ParametricNDSolve[
  {
   M'[r] == M[r]. {{k, -1}, {-1, k}} + {{k, 1}, {1, -k}},
   M[0] == {{Sqrt[k], 0}, {0, Sqrt[k]}}
   }
  , M, {r, 0, 1}, {k}]
```

[image: M]

The solution to $M$ at any $r$ (here, between 0 and 1) and parameter value $k$ can be determined with:

```
M[k][r] /. soln
```

Let's define $G(r,k)=\textrm{Tr}[\textrm{Im} M(r,k)]$. (I think the solutions to $M$ are real matrices for $k>0$.)

```
G[r_, k_] := Tr[Im[Evaluate[M[k][r] /. soln]]
```

Finally, the $G(r,k)$ can be plotted with a function like:

```
ContourPlot[
  G[r, k],
 {k, -5, 0}, {r, 0, 1},  FrameLabel -> {"k", "Tr[Im M]"}]
```

[image: G]

Comment: Thanks for your effort, this is precisely what I was looking for. I've made an edit to the question, $G$ is actually just $M$ (sorry for the typo). You may want to make an edit to your answer accordingly.

Comment: You're welcome, this was fun.  I've made a few changes to my answer since I had the arguments to the `ParametricFunction` reversed.